# Add delay to stop().hide()

Tags: jquery

I am showing/hiding a div on hover over another div.

```
$(".div1, .div2").hover(
function () {
    $(".div2").stop().show('slow');
}, function () {
    $(".div2").stop().hide('slow');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zvbtL71L/

This works fine. However, the divs have a small space between them, so there is either a slight jump effect when the cursor moves to the second div, or it disappears if the cursor is in the gap between them.

It would be sufficient for my needs to solve this by add a delay in hiding the second div. How can I add a short delay to the hide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.div1').hover(function() {
    var $target = $('.div2');
    clearTimeout($target.data('hoverTimer'));
    $target.stop().slideDown(500);
  }, function() {
    var $target = $('.div2');
    var timer = setTimeout(function() {
      $target.stop().slideUp();
    }, 200);
    $target.data('hoverTimer', timer);
  });

  $('.div2').hover(function() {
    clearTimeout($(this).data('hoverTimer'));
  }, function() {
    $(this).stop().slideUp();
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.div1,
.div2 {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px
}
.div1 {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff
}
.div2 {
  background: #eee;
}
.div2 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1">Hover over me</div>
  <div class="div2">Show hide me</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found that setting up timers etc in order to solve problems like this always gets messy and requires a lot of code. If you're trying to do these kinds of things often, you really should consider an animation library such as GSAP. Using their delay and overwrite functions, this becomes a piece of cake:

```
$(".div1, .div2").hover(
function () {
    tweenMax.to($(".div2"), .5, {display:'block', overwrite:1});
}, function () {
    tweenMax.to($(".div2"), .5, {display:'none', delay:.1});
});
```